# how to detect occurrence of specific word in audio stream.

Tags: java, audio, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

At first I thought it will be as simple as image recognition.

Create FANN hopfield network and instead of training/feeding it with binary converted image feeding it with binary converted sound.

but:

1. How to convert wav to binary string (I believe I need it in binary not byte- am I right?)
2. How to make it continuous, I mean counting occurrences of word/sound from microphone as a source.
3. What is best java library to do this ( not SPHINX or other voice recognition library - I want to make my code language independent, or even recognize custom sounds - like clapping your hands)

I used FANN before for image recognition and I know about Encog but maybe there is somthing better(or simpler, I don't actually understand how to use Encog) and preferable java native for easy porting to mobile devices

Comment: I know you might have forgotten but how you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already able to work with images, maybe this is what you need:
http://code.google.com/p/asperes/

It can convert WAV sound samples to BMP images (spectrograms) and arbitrary BMP images to sound (WAV).

Description from the documentation:

Audio Spectrograph and Re-Synthesis (ASPERES) is a small command line utility that can generate images (spectrograms) from sound samples, and sounds from arbitrary images.

Comment: Yes that's a great approach to the problem. But considering that I need a java library to generate spectrograms in my application.